# Improve CollectionView loading speed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a calendar view with a year overview:

[image: I build it to look exactly like the iOS Calendar]

For that I have the following View hierarchy:

- ViewController

  - View

    - Collection View with 12 cells (One for each month)

      - Colleciton View with 49 cells (One for each day + in and out dates + days of week)

Now when it comes to the following code part where I load the cells for the days inside the overview:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarPageYearCollectionCellMonthCell;

    print("cell for item at: \(indexPath.item)");

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale;

    cell.label.text = self.days[indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}
```

This code part takes over 9 seconds. Meanwhile the UI is frozen. How can I improve the loading and rendering speed of those cells significantly so that it wont take more than 1 second to load the view?

**EDIT** I found out which part of the code is consuming this amount of time. I created a `UICollectionViewCell` programmatically:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class CalendarPageYearCollectionCellMonthCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    var label: UILabel! = nil;

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);

        self.setupView();
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;

        self.label = UILabel();
        self.label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12);
        self.label.textColor = PaintBox.colorWithName(VKBColor.black, andAlpha: 1.0);
        self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        self.label.textAlignment = .center;
        self.sizeToFit();
        self.label.center = self.center;

        self.addSubview(self.label);
    }
}
```

So when I use this code the Calendar loads really fast. But with that code, ofcourse, you will never see the label which you added as a subview. So I need to add some constraints:

```
func setupView() {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;

    self.label = UILabel();
    self.label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 12);
    self.label.textColor = PaintBox.colorWithName(VKBColor.black, andAlpha: 1.0);
    self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    self.label.textAlignment = .center;
    self.sizeToFit();
    self.label.center = self.center;

    self.addSubview(self.label);

    self.label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview();
    }
}
```

And now it takes ages for the view to load. So the real problem seems to be the constraints.

Isnt there a ways to just create a cell only one time and copy that to all other cells with just setting the text?

Comment: First question: Why rasterize? It looks like pretty simple cells - a label plus a circle (only on 1 day)...

Comment: That was my frustrated try to speed up everything, since it was the only result I got from research

Comment: Have you used Instruments to determine exactly where the time is being spent?

Comment: Are you using any custom fonts in this? Sometimes if we use custom fonts &  we didn't copy those into our bundle & add into the .plist file, in that case, it takes more time to load very first time.

Comment: The XCode profiler is telling me that it needs all the time when dequeueing the reusable cells. Since I got 12 * 49 cells it summs up to over 9 seconds to show the view. I dont use any custom fonts.

Comment: Are your cells loaded from `xib`s? Have you tried converting them to code?

Comment: Using Code instead of xibs fasts everything up but it takes still much time. 4 seconds instead of 9.

Comment: Curious... what all are you doing when you create each cell? Try temporarily using a plain `UITableViewCell` and doing nothing else to it, and see how long it takes to generate everything. If it's quick, then I'd suggest going step by step in whatever else your cell-setup code is doing, and see when / where you get a performance hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lot of researching I came to the conclusion that I cannot speed this up while using storyboards and constraints. It is always slow as hell.

So I tried to get rid of all xib files, storyboard files and constraints. The result was incredible. I made it from a view loading speed of 9 seconds to a loading speed of 230 ms.

So what I recommend to everybody: If you have performance issues just dont use xib's, storyboard's or constraints. Just code everything yourself and set all frames of your views directly.